# discord.js: How can I make the bot send mention, but not in an embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I was working on my join message and was curious how can I make the bot send mention not in an embed, like this: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlnet.png)

And I Have like this:[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDgQk.png)

My current code is:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async(member) => { // this event gets triggered when a new member joins the server!

    const Channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('761871578178387989') 
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`:wave:   Hello ${member.user.tag} and welcome to **${member.guild.name}**.`)
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
        .addField('Consider checking it!', '**Server IP:** play.aftnetwork.net\n**Store:** https://store.aftnetwork.net\n\n**Make sure to check <#761874528702824469>.**', true)
        .setFooter(`AftNetwork`)
        .setColor('#468DFF')
    // sends a message to the channel
    Channel.send(embed)
})
```

What should I add to this code to get the wanted result? Help pls <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using the [TextChannel.send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method, which accepts an optional `options` argument ([MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions)) as the second parameter, in which you can specify the embed.

---

Here's an example:

```js
Channel.send(member, {
    embed: embed,
});
// member is the GuildMember that joined your server and embed is your MessageEmbed.
```